# How to access a member of object in native query params with 'IN' clause in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table
WHERE field_one = '1000'
  AND (field_two, field_three, field_four) IN (('70033100', '0090047002', 'CAT'), ('70033100', '0004712', 'SAT'), ('70031337', '0233263', 'DAT'), ('70033100', '0090000001', 'CAT'))
  AND field_type IN ('TYPE_1', 'TYPE_2')
  AND date <= '2022-09-17'
```

I need to write corresponding JPA native query. I have a Entity Class given below, which is referred by query above.

```
  class Entity {
    String field_one;
    String field_two;
    String field_three;
    String field_four;
    LocalDate date;
    String field_type;
    }
```

I understand that we can simply refer the list in jpa query like `:list`, for example I can have a method like

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,
value = "SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE field_one IN :field_one_list")
public List<Entity> findByFieldOneList(List<String> field_one_list)
```

How to do it for the given query?

Comment: You cannot for a native(SQL) query - with SQL, just as in your example SQL, every parameter must be bound individually. JPQL on the other hand can break out the list parameter in the JPQL string into individual parameters when building the SQL statement. Simply @Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.field_one IN :field_one_list")

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. names should be camelCase not snake_case

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```java
@Query(value="select * from data_table where field_one = '1000' And (field_two, field_three, field_four) IN :?1 And field_type = ?2 And date <='2022-09-17'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Entity> findByEntityConditions(String[] data, String[] fieldType);
```

Take data and fieldType as String Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Query( SELECT *
FROM data_table
WHERE field_one = '1000'
AND (field_two, field_three, field_four) IN (:param1)
AND field_type IN (:param2)
AND date <= '2022-09-17', nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> findByCustomData(@Param("param1")List<String> list1, @Param("param2) List<String> list2)
```